# Mysql connector for python dosent add data into table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

The code runs with no errors but doesn't add the data to the table.

```py
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", 
   user="user", 
   passwd="pass", 
   db="database",
   autocommit=True) 
def welcome_new_user():
    pass1 = input("Enter your master password")
    pass2 = input("Enter your master password again")
    if pass1 == pass2:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MasterPass(masterpassword) VALUES (%s)", [pass1])
    else:
        print("Passwords don't match")
     
x = cursor.execute("SELECT * from MasterPass ")
if x == None:
    print("nope")
    welcome_new_user()
```

it prints `pass added` but the table still remains empty

Comment: How is `cursor` defined?

Comment: `cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)`